# How to Paginate in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database. When i am fetching data it has many rows. I want to break this result. I read many tutorials about pagination but not understand how to paginate.
Below is My Code-

```
<?php
                if(isset($_GET['search_profile'])){
                $gender = $_GET['Gender'];
                $religion = $_GET['selected_religion'];
                $caste = $_GET['selected_caste'];
                $marital_status = $_GET['marital_status'];
                $lage = $_GET['lage'];
                $hage = $_GET['hage'];

                $current_date = date('Y');
                            $hage1 = date('Y') - $hage;
                //echo $hage1;
            //  echo "<br>";
                $lage1 = date('Y') - $lage;
                //echo $lage1;



                $qq = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE yyyy BETWEEN '$hage1' AND '$lage1' AND gender='$gender' 
                AND religion LIKE '%$religion%'
                AND caste LIKE '%$caste%'
                AND marital_status LIKE '%$marital_status%'";

$profile_query_result = mysql_query($qq, $dbc)
or die('Error1'.mysql_error());


                }
                ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: _"not understand how to paginate"_ - so what have you tried?

Comment: You know our civilization is evolving when you're selecting `caste`

Comment: what's wrong with any one of the tutorials, if you don't understand them, will you understand us any better?

Comment: I am using ajax for caste. @njk

Comment: @AzharKhan I was making a comment that there are still caste systems in some societies.

Comment: @njk Okay. I have a code for this. Whenever someone select Religion the caste box automatically shown. Using Ajax. I want to paginate this result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LIMIT keyword to tell MySQL how many records to fetch, and specify a starting offset

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM members 
   WHERE yyyy BETWEEN '$hage1' AND '$lage1' 
     AND gender='$gender' 
     AND religion LIKE '%$religion%'
     AND caste LIKE '%$caste%'     
     AND marital_status LIKE '%$marital_status%'
  LIMIT 0,100
```

The above SQL query will return the first 100 records, starting with the first

If you'd like the next 100 (i.e. 100 records starting from recrod #101) then you would use `LIMIT 100, 100`; Then for the next 100 `LIMIT 200,100` and so on..

Of course, if you wish to control the page number from PHP you would use a parameter instead of hard-coded values, like so:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM members 
   WHERE yyyy BETWEEN '$hage1' AND '$lage1' 
     AND gender='$gender' 
     AND religion LIKE '%$religion%'
     AND caste LIKE '%$caste%'     
     AND marital_status LIKE '%$marital_status%'
  LIMIT '$offset', '$recordsPerPage'
```

Then $offset should take values in increments of $recordsPerPage (i.e. 0, 100, 200, ...n*100) and $recordsPerPage can be whatever number of records you wish to display on each page (typically 10, 20 or 100)

Comment: how do i use links to do pagination?

Comment: what do you mean by "links"?

Comment: well, all you need to do is display the links on your page and set the href of the link to contain the page number. Then from PHP you will use that number to compute the start offset to feed into the query as I show above.

Answer (score 0):

If client-side pagination is not a problem, a simple solution is to use Jquery pagination. You can see an example at http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html

In your JavaScript code add:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

Where 'example' is the Id if your  element.

Comment: and, may I ask, why would you want to use client-side pagination? how is this really relevant to the question?

Comment: The question is about paginating results in a PHP. So, as I see it, the obvious solution is to use a `LIMIT` operation in th query. But, as Azhar says that he has got problems in implementing it, I suggested to use client side pagination because it is really easy to implement in a webpage. Also, the suggested library adds ordering and filtering to the table (client-side). I know it is not the best approach, and that it will fail when there're too many rows, but I used it in several projects and it works well.

Comment: The problem with doing client side pagination is that it's really only useful from a UI stand point. It's not going to help performance at all.. And since he's obviously a beginner, you should make sure to point this out to him!

Comment: I completely agree. Client-side pagination is intended to help the end-user only. It's by this reason that it only should be used where it will not cause big overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished my first pagination script the other day.  It wasn't that hard.  Honestly I would be happy to help you understand the logic of it but I am not going to code it for you - I also believe this topic has been covered on these boards and this is a possible duplicate.

How much PHP do you know?  The logic behind your pagination script (assuming the data is coming from a database) is something like this:

**You need at least 2 database queries**
-Your first query will tell you how many results there are and your second query will actually provide the results.

**There are a few variables you will need** - You will need to know the number of items.  You will also need to know the limit - that is, how many items can appear on each page.  You find the number of pages by dividing the limit from the number of items (# of items / limit per page )

**The Display HTML** - To create the HTML of the pagination I used a series of if statements.  Kind of like the following pseudo code:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) {
       $page = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/', '', $_GET['page'] );
}
else {
       $page = 1;
}


/* the following code will not work
   with the identity (===) operator 
   because when coming from get $page
is a string not an int */

if ( $current_page == 1 ) {

     $page2 = $page + 1;
     $page3 = $page + 2;
     $page4 = $page + 3;


     $pagination .= "<div>Pg $page</div>";

    // if theres a second page, display page 2
    if ( $num_of_posts > ( $limit * 1 ) ) {
         $pagination .= "<a>$page2 &gt;</a>";
    }

    // if there is a 3rd page
    if ( $num_of_posts > ( $limit * 2 ) ) {
         $pagination .= "<a>$page3 &gt;</a>";
    }

    // if there is a 4th page
    if ( $num_of_posts > ( $limit * 3 ) ) {
         $pagination .= "<a>$page4 &gt;</a>";
    }

    // if there is more than 4 pages
    if ( ($page4 != $last_page && $page3 != $last_page ) {
         $pagination .= "<a href='" . $last_page . "'>&gt; &gt;</a>";
    }
}
```

This process will need to be repeated.  How much you repeat it is entirely up to you.  You can rewrite the if / elseif statements as a switch statement, I personally do not use the switch statement in web programming.

You can take the same approach to ( $page == 2 ), ( $page == $last_page ), ( $page == ( $last_page - 1 ).  You can go overboard.  This simply ensures that the HTML output will be appropriate if there is only one or two pages of content.

**The Second Query** - The second query will fetch the results from the database.  The limit will be ( ( $page - 1 ) * $limit_per_page ), $limit_per_page

ie:

```
 $limit = ( $page - 1) * $limit_per_page
   $sql= "SELECT post, user, id, etc, whatever
         FROM table
         WHERE this = that
         ORDER BY foobarz ASC[/DESC]
         LIMIT ".$limit.",".$limit_per_page;
```

I hope this explains it enough for you to build it!  Good luck!  Let me know if you need any more explaining!